# Angular - set controller variable after service $http call

Tags: angularjs, callback, promise

I'm finding it difficult making sense of all the differing blogs and examples out there on how to use a promise correctly in angular, so would appreciate some clarification from someone please.

Is using a callback passed in to the service get method to set the controller variable like this wrong?

In the *Session* service:

```
self.getSessions = function(callback) {

  $http.get(self.urls.sessionsList).then(
    function (response) {
      callback(response.data);
    },
    function (response) {
      // failure
    }
  );

};
```

from this controller:

```
.controller('SessionsController', ['Session', function(Session) {
  var self = this;

  self.sessions = [];

  Session.getSessions(function(data) {
    self.sessions = data;
  });
}])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Q) Is using a callback passed in to the service get method to set the controller >>variable like this wrong?.

No, it is not wrong, but you can use the power of the promise and change your code to be something like below, where you can chain to the "then" method :

```
self.getSessions = function() {

       return $http.get(self.urls.sessionsList);
}
```

and change your controller code to be:

```
.controller('SessionsController', ['Session', function(Session) {
  var self = this;

  self.sessions = [];

  Session.getSessions().then(function(response) {
    self.sessions = response.data;
  });
}]);
```

Then, you can see that the caller can chain the to "then" and do more and more functionality,...

hope that helps.

Comment: The first code snippet is deferred antipattern in its canonical form. It has to be `return $http.get(self.urls.sessionsList)` one-liner.

Comment: Thanks Omar. I understand this difference, but then my controller has to handle the $http error path as well.  Doesn't this make the controller too messy?  Shouldn't just binding UI code be in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Use Deffered promise is bad thing since es6 promise is released

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand what you're trying to say sorry.

Comment: Sorry I'm not very good with English, I am trying to say that before a guy recommended to use defered promises but it is not a good things since ecma 6 is out.